# How to fix .Exception: 'Custom pin not found for specific pins

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Please help me with this issue.**
**I was making a custom renderer in xamarin using this article:**
[Xamarin Form Custom Renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/customrenderers-map-pin/)

Everything worked fine until I made the pin information into a JSON file.

So basically now the **LAT, LNG, label,** name and URL were stored in a **JSON file instead of a C# file**.
For testing, I had made 3 temporary pins. But only 1 of them shows the custom rendered window. When I click the other 2 pins an exception occurs as custom pin not found. But the custom pin is found for the last pin but not the 1st and 2nd pin which confuses me.

My code:

**JSON file:**

```
[

{"Label"   :"Country1",
        "Address":"A multine paragraph",
        "Lat":"-12",
        "Lng":"14",
        "Name":"Xamarin",
         "Url": "http://xamarin.com/about/"
},


{ "Label"  :"Country2",
         "Address":"Multiline paragraph",
         "Lat":"-25", 
         "Lng":"45",
         "Name":"Xamarin",
         "Url": "http://xamarin.com/about/"
},

{ "Label"  :"Country3",
         "Address":"Multiline paragraph",
         "Lat":"-5", 
         "Lng":"45",
         "Name":"Xamarin",
         "Url": "http://xamarin.com/about/"
}

]
```

**MapPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using System.Reflection;    

namespace Orbage
{
    public partial class MapPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MapPage()
        {
            CustomMap customMap = new CustomMap
            {
                MapType = MapType.Hybrid


            };

            Content = customMap;

            var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(MapPage)).Assembly;
            Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Orbage.Mydata.json");
            string json = "";
            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
            {
                json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            var places = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Mydata>>(json);



            List<CustomPin> custompinList = new List<CustomPin>();
            foreach (var place in places)
            {
                CustomPin pin = new CustomPin
                {
                    Type = PinType.Place,
                    Position = new Position(Double.Parse(place.Lat), Double.Parse(place.Lng)),
                    Label = place.Label,
                    Address = place.Address,
                    Name = place.Name,
                    Url = place.Url
                };
                
                
                customMap.Pins.Add(pin);
                customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(37.79752, -122.40183), Distance.FromMiles(1.0)));
                customMap.CustomPins = custompinList; 
            }
            

        }
    }
    public class Mydata
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Lat { get; set; }
        public string Lng { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }


    }
}
```

CustomPin:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

namespace Orbage
{
    public class CustomPin : Pin
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Adress { get; set; }
        public string Lat { get; set; }
        public string Lng { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CustomMap:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

namespace Orbage
{
    public class CustomMap : Map
    {
        public List<CustomPin> CustomPins { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**CustomMapRenderer.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using Android.Widget;
using ----;
using ----.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMap), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]
namespace ----.Droid
{
    public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer, GoogleMap.IInfoWindowAdapter
    {
        List<CustomPin> customPins;

        public CustomMapRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                NativeMap.InfoWindowClick -= OnInfoWindowClick;
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
                customPins = formsMap.CustomPins;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)
        {
            base.OnMapReady(map);

            NativeMap.InfoWindowClick += OnInfoWindowClick;
            NativeMap.SetInfoWindowAdapter(this);
        }

        protected override MarkerOptions CreateMarker(Pin pin)
        {
            var marker = new MarkerOptions();
            marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Position.Longitude));
            marker.SetTitle(pin.Label);
            marker.SetSnippet(pin.Address);
            marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.pin));
            return marker;
        }

        void OnInfoWindowClick(object sender, GoogleMap.InfoWindowClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var customPin = GetCustomPin(e.Marker);
            if (customPin == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customPin.Url))
            {
                var url = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(customPin.Url);
                var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, url);
                intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        public Android.Views.View GetInfoContents(Marker marker)
        {
            var inflater = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as Android.Views.LayoutInflater;
            if (inflater != null)
            {
                Android.Views.View view;

                var customPin = GetCustomPin(marker);
                if (customPin == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
                }

                if (customPin.Name.Equals("Xamarin"))
                {
                    view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.XamarinMapInfoWindow, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MapInfoWindow, null);
                }

                var infoTitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowTitle);
                var infoSubtitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowSubtitle);

                if (infoTitle != null)
                {
                    infoTitle.Text = marker.Title;
                }
                if (infoSubtitle != null)
                {
                    infoSubtitle.Text = marker.Snippet;
                }

                return view;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public Android.Views.View GetInfoWindow(Marker marker)
        {
            return null;
        }

        CustomPin GetCustomPin(Marker annotation)
        {
            var position = new Position(annotation.Position.Latitude, annotation.Position.Longitude);
            foreach (var pin in customPins)
            {
                if (pin.Position == position)
                {
                    return pin;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for seeing this and I hope this get's answered and someone with the same error gets it fixed.
:)

I tried debugging and here is a image of what somewhat might help:
[image]

Comment: first, this is not a system exception, it is an exception that you are explicitly throwing in your own code.  You need to debug `GetCustomPin` to see why it is not finding the pin when you click on it.

Comment: I am incredibly sorry about that. I by mistakenly copied the system part too. I will edit it but how would I debug it if it works for one pin in the same data list but the rest aren't working

Comment: Use the debugger.  Look at the position value that is passed in and compare it to the values in your data to see why it is not finding a match

Comment: Okay, I will try to fix it. I will do it and check why can't it find a match. Thanks I will try.

Comment: Everything else except this is fine so this just might be the problem.

Comment: Did you actually use the debugger?  As in setting a breakpoint and stepping through your code?  That appears to be some random console message that doesn’t mean anything.

Comment: When I add the breakpoint in MapPage.xaml.cs xaml hot reload fails.

Comment: So i think the error must be in MapPage.xaml.cs

Comment: add a bunch of `Console.WriteLine` statements in `GetCustomPin` to output the coordinate you are looking for and the coordinates of each pin as you loop through them.  It may be that they differ by a few decimal places instead of being an exact match.  I don't know.  But you seem to be focusing on issues that have nothing to do with the actual error you're getting

Comment: I am trying as much as I can. I reopened working on this app again just a few days ago. Before this I was trying Java so I have forgotten a little but I will get it fixed.

Comment: I have been trying for a while but I can't find the root of the problem @Jason

Comment: have you tried any of the things I suggested?

Comment: Yes i did add many watches and breakpoints at the code i suspected but couldn't find the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  foreach (var place in places)
        {
            CustomPin pin = new CustomPin
            {
                Type = PinType.Place,
                Position = new Position(Double.Parse(place.Lat), Double.Parse(place.Lng)),
                Label = place.Label,
                Address = place.Address,
                Name = place.Name,
                Url = place.Url
            };
            customMap.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> { pin }; //this will cause your customMap.CustomPins always has only the last custompin. 
            customMap.Pins.Add(pin);
            customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(37.79752, -122.40183), Distance.FromMiles(1.0)));
        }
```

The issue is here,you add the customMap.CustomPins inside the loop,so it always has only the third CustomPin.

Try to move it out of the  `foreach`:

```
  List<CustomPin> custompinList = new List<CustomPin>();
  foreach (var place in places)
        {
            CustomPin pin = new CustomPin
            {
                Type = PinType.Place,
                Position = new Position(Double.Parse(place.Lat), Double.Parse(place.Lng)),
                Label = place.Label,
                Address = place.Address,
                Name = place.Name,
                Url = place.Url
            };
            custompinList.Add(pin);
            customMap.Pins.Add(pin);
            customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(37.79752, -122.40183), Distance.FromMiles(1.0)));
        }
  customMap.CustomPins = custompinList;
```

**Update** the effect like below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: But  when I do put it as the pin is made in the foreach how would I access it outside?

Comment: @ItsRaptorman What do you want to access outside ?

Comment: It still gives the exception even if the custompinlist is outside.

Comment: And now both the pins can't be found.

Comment: @ItsRaptorman I test it,it works well,the screen shot like above.If you want to access one  pin,you could call it with it index in the list like `custompinList[index]`.

Comment: I did not understand what you meant. @leo Zhu - MSFT

Comment: The last pin does look the same. But I did not understand what you meant by update the effect like below as the last pin does look like that. I haven't made any changes to the renderer till now. And when I put it outside of foreach it gives the exception for all of them. When it's inside it only displays last pin and the rest give exception but after I put it outside all of them give exception. I am really confused. @Leo Zhu - MSFT

Comment: @ItsRaptorman I just change parts of the codes of the sample with your custompins.Could you show the current newest codes of the page?

Comment: Okay I will edit the question. Please see the question now. @Leo Zhu - MSFT

Comment: I've updated the question with the new code. Please check it now.

Comment: @ItsRaptorman Move the custompinList out of the foreach.This line `customMap.CustomPins = custompinList;`

Comment: Yes it still shows exception customPin not found for all of them.

Comment: @ItsRaptorman You miss the `custompinList.Add(pin);` in your foreach.

Comment: Thanks alot. It finally works. After alot of tries it finally works! Thanks so much for your time on this question and I hope whoever else also tries do like me and get this error finds this answer. :) @Leo Zhu - MSFT