# Custom Map Pin is not found

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms Map Application, I am using a Custom Map Renderer using [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map-pin) for Android.
I successfully managed to construct a single pin.
Now I wanted to make several pins, so to make the code less repetitive, I added my data(example data) to a Mydata.json file and made it read from it. However only one pin data works, and in the case of many the application only considers the last pin data.
Here's the data.json:

```
[

{"Label"   :"Country1",
        "Address":"A multine paragraph",
        "Lat":"-12",
        "Lng":"14",
        "Name":"Tamarin",
         "Url": "http://xamarin.com/about/"
},


{ "Label"  :"Country2",
        "Address":"Multiline paragraph",
        "Lat":"-25", 
        "Lng":"45",
        "Name":"Camarin",
        "Url": "http://xamarin.com/about/"
},

{ "Label"  :"Country3",
         "Address":"Multiline paragraphMultiline paragraphMultiline paragraphMultiline paragraphMultiline paragraphMultiline paragraphMultiline paragraphMultiline paragraph",
         "Lat":"-5", 
         "Lng":"45",
         "Name":"Xamarin",
         "Url": "http://xamarin.com/about/"
}

]
```

And here's my CustomMapRenderer for it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using Android.Widget;
using Orbage;
using Orbage.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMap), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]
namespace Orbage.Droid
{
    public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer, GoogleMap.IInfoWindowAdapter
    {
        List<CustomPin> customPins;

        public CustomMapRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                NativeMap.InfoWindowClick -= OnInfoWindowClick;
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
                customPins = formsMap.CustomPins;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)
        {
            base.OnMapReady(map);

            NativeMap.InfoWindowClick += OnInfoWindowClick;
            NativeMap.SetInfoWindowAdapter(this);
        }

        protected override MarkerOptions CreateMarker(Pin pin)
        {
            var marker = new MarkerOptions();
            marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Position.Longitude));
            marker.SetTitle(pin.Label);
            marker.SetSnippet(pin.Address);
            marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.pin));
            return marker;
        }

        void OnInfoWindowClick(object sender, GoogleMap.InfoWindowClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var customPin = GetCustomPin(e.Marker);
            if (customPin == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customPin.Url))
            {
                var url = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(customPin.Url);
                var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, url);
                intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        public Android.Views.View GetInfoContents(Marker marker)
        {
            var inflater = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as Android.Views.LayoutInflater;
            if (inflater != null)
            {
                Android.Views.View view;

                var customPin = GetCustomPin(marker);
                if (customPin == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
                }

                if (customPin.Name.Equals("Xamarin"))
                {
                    view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.XamarinMapInfoWindow, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MapInfoWindow, null);
                }

                var infoTitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowTitle);
                var infoSubtitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowSubtitle);

                if (infoTitle != null)
                {
                    infoTitle.Text = marker.Title;
                }
                if (infoSubtitle != null)
                {
                    infoSubtitle.Text = marker.Snippet;
                }

                return view;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public Android.Views.View GetInfoWindow(Marker marker)
        {
            return null;
        }

        CustomPin GetCustomPin(Marker annotation)
        {
            var position = new Position(annotation.Position.Latitude, annotation.Position.Longitude);
            foreach (var pin in customPins)
            {
                if (pin.Position == position)
                {
                    return pin;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Where I've set my pin:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

namespace Orbage
{
    public class CustomPin : Pin
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The rest of the code is just a step-by-step adaptation from the Microsoft documentation, however, do let me know if I've misjudged the amount of code required to analyze my problem.

As you see, from line 82, the second exception turns out to be true; that is the custom pin is null; but the pin is present in the data file, and it's unable to read it for some reason, I am unable to figure out the reason for this. I believe it has something to do with the object reference but I can't find where my problem lies.
I apologise in advance for any obvious reasons, if there are any; as I am not that well-versed with this
Thanks.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger?

Comment: Can you show me the code where you create multiple pins?

Comment: @Jason No, I've not done it yet; I'll have a look

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Jason's comment, and this post from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65763631/how-to-fix-exception-custom-pin-not-found-for-specific-pins) I was able to find out the problem.

```
customMap.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> { pin };
```

This was inside foreach in my MapPage.xaml.cs:

```
foreach (var place in places)
            {
              CustomPin pin = new CustomPin
               {
                 Type = PinType.Place,
                 Position = new Position(Double.Parse(place.Lat), Double.Parse(place.Lng)),
                Label = place.Label,
                 Address = place.Address,
                 Name = place.Name,
                 Url = place.Url
             };
              customMap.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> { pin }; //This one
              customMap.Pins.Add(pin);
              customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(37.79752, -122.40183), Distance.FromMiles(1.0)));
```

By placing it outside, it could call for each pin.

```
 List<CustomPin> custompinList = new List<CustomPin>(); //Outside the foreach now
 foreach (var place in places)
 {
     CustomPin pin = new CustomPin
     {
         Type = PinType.Place,
         Position = new Position(Double.Parse(place.Lat), Double.Parse(place.Lng)),
         Label = place.Label,
         Address = place.Address,
         Name = place.Name,
         Url = place.Url
     };
     custompinList.Add(pin);
     customMap.Pins.Add(pin);
     customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(37.79752, -122.40183), Distance.FromMiles(1.0)));
 }
```

And that resolves the problem.